# polling process by kill -0 frequently

Tags: shell, kill, posix, sleep

The following script in Linux prints "sleep 1 finished", but in general POSIX you can not use `sleep 0.1`, since the argument has to be integer. If I leave the command out, the script will never exit (why!?), but takes very much CPU power. If I replace it by `( : )` it works in my system, but I am not sure, if it will in general, and even that takes a lot of CPU power. What is a better POSIX solution?

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 2 &
pid=$!
sleep 1 &
pid_sleep=$!
while kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; do
    kill -0 "$pid_sleep" 2>/dev/null || {
        echo sleep 1 finished
        exit 0
    }
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to wait for the sleep to exit would be with the `wait` command:

```
sleep 2 &
pid=$!
sleep 1 &
pid_sleep=$!

wait $pid $pid_sleep
echo "commands finished"
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to know which command finished first, and it is enough that one of them finishes.